# Cannot resolve substring() or indexOf() methods

Tags: android

I am new to android and i am trying to search for a certain character in an edit text and then extract all the characters before it in a new variable using the substring() and indexOf() methods , but android studio saying that it cannot solve either method . So please tell me what i am doing wrong with the code. Here is the declaration for the edit text :

```
EditText text;
text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

And the code for calling these methods :

```
if(text.getText().toString().contains("+")) {
    String before = text.substring(text.indexOf("+") - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `substring()` and `indexOf()` on your `text` variable, which is an `EditText` object, and they're `string` methods. Convert to string first and then use them, like so:

```
String textString = text.getText().toString();
if(textString.contains("+")) {
    String before = textString.substring(textString.indexOf("+") - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to call them in the same way you call contains(): text.getText().toString() because the two methods are part of the String class, not EditText.

Answer (score 0):

You can try String before = text.split("+")[0]; This will return you everything before the first '+'